# Error when trying to Add Lookup in workflow email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am trying to add some `Lookups` to a Workflow email. When I choose the `Lookup` I want to be displayed in the email, I get an error saying:

`A workflow lookup cannot be copied and pasted from one email message to another. You should create new lookups (click Add or Change Lookup), and then delete the lookups that were copied and pasted.`

The error suggests it all, BUT I am not copy/pasting any lookups into the email. I click on the button to add a look up and select it to add.

I am trying to lookup a value for **Current Item** so my lookup looks as follows `[%Current Item:Start Date & Time%]`. I am able to add other Lookups for the **Current Item** but nothing to do with "Time & Date". The form was built through SharePoint Designer 2013 as well as the Workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs if the **lookups column names** have a special character like & , > .

So in your case try to replace

```
[%Current Item:Start Date & Time%]
```

with

```
[%Current Item:Start Date and Time%]
```

Or change the column name in your list setting to be `Start Date and Time`

Or define a workflow variable and set it to this value `[%Current Item:Start Date & Time%]` , then use the workflow variable in your email message

Comment: you are welcome my bro @IE5Master , should you upvote and set it as answer if it solved your issue :)

Comment: Issue resolved by using WorkFlow Variable. Thanks